# Resolving "AttributeError: module 'dask.bag' has no attribute 'from_filenames'"

Tags: python, dask

I am following a simple tutorial to load Reddit comment data from pushshift.io into a dask bag.  I am getting the strange error: "Resolving "AttributeError: module 'dask.bag' has no attribute 'from_filenames'", despite the fact that this is standard procedure as described here: http://dask.pydata.org/en/doc-test-build/bag.html

```
import dask
import dask.bag as db

data = db.from_filenames("reddit_1_28_2018.txt", chunkbytes=100000).map(json.loads)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-bcbd31affbfb> in <module>()
      2 import dask.bag as db
      3 
----> 4 data = db.from_filenames("reddit_1_28_2018.txt", chunkbytes=100000).map(json.loads)

AttributeError: module 'dask.bag' has no attribute 'from_filenames'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the resource you were looking at was very old.  I recommend reading [the Dask documentation](https://dask.pydata.org/) for up-to-date information.

I suspect that you're looking for [db.read_text](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/bag-creation.html#db-read-text)